# SSRS - Hiding a column but how to bunch up other fields

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

I'm using SSRS and I've hidden a column by adding an expression to the Visibility property of a Text Box.  While this does indeed hide the column when the expression is True, it leaves a blank space now - how do I bunch up the columns to the left and right of the hidden column?  I've set Can Shrink = True but this doesn't appear to have any effect.

Comment: In short, you can't do this. The only option generally it to convert from a table to a matrix but that would likely mean updating your dataset query to work in a matrix. Show you report design and some sample data if you want more help in that direction.

Comment: thank for confirming - I will workaround this by making it the last column then if its hidden it won't create a gap.